# How do I make a custom logger for Fluent Assertions?

Tags: c#, nunit, .net

I'm using NUnit and Fluent Assertions for testing. I'd like to write a custom logger for my test steps which shows which steps have passed and the step (if any) that failed. It looks like someone [has done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049700/how-can-i-add-log-messages-to-an-nunit-test-that-will-appear-in-a-nant-build-exe), but I'm not sure how that person accomplished it.

I've tried extending [FluentAssertions.Common.Services.ThrowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760245/customize-failure-handling-in-fluentassertions), but that of course doesn't get called for successful test steps.